# CMake ExternalProject Recloning for Every Configuration

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-platform

I have a cross-platform library which I am building with CMake. I have created a CMakePreset.txt file to store all of my configuration and build presets and use the Visual Studio Code CMake Tools extension for building my library. Some of the configurations I require are Win x32, Win x64, UWP ARM, UWP ARM64, Android ARM, Android ARM64, etc.

My library depends upon an external library which I clone and build with the use of [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html). This library is very large (20GB) therefore I only want to clone the library once and build for all the different platforms I require. To do this, I am trying to set the `SOURCE_DIR` to within my library directory, i.e. my_library/external/external_library. This works, however when I change my configuration preset the clone is deleted and recloned, which is an long operation. This only happens the first time of building a specific configuration, however can be frustrating when multiple developers are working on the library.

Is there anyway I can tell `ExternalProject` not to reclone the external library if the `SOURCE_DIR` already exists? I would like to continuing using the Git download commands provided by `ExternalProject`, if possible.

The following contains an example of my presets and CMakeLists files.

### my_library/CMakePresets.txt

```
{
    "version": 4,
    "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
        "major": 3,
        "minor": 23,
        "patch": 0
    },
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "win_x64",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build/win_x64",
            "generator": "Ninja Multi-Config"
        },
        {
            "name": "android_arm64",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build/android_arm64",
            "generator": "Ninja Multi-Config"
        },
        ...
    ],
    "buildPresets": [
        {
            "name": "rel_win_x64",
            "configurePreset": "win_x64",
            "configuration": "Release"
        },
        {
            "name": "rel_android_arm64",
            "configurePreset": "android_arm64",
            "configuration": "Release"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

### my_library/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

project(my_library VERSION 1.0)

add_subdirectory(external)

add_library(my_library src/example.cc include/example.h)

target_link_libraries(my_library external_library)
```

### my_library/external/CMakeLists.txt

```
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(external_library_src
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external_library
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/ExternalLibrary/external_library.git
    GIT_TAG version_tag
    UPDATES_DISCONNECTED true
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND configure_command
    BUILD_COMMAND build_command
)

add_library(external_library STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
add_dependencies(external_library external_library_src)
```

Comment: do all your configuration presets build to the same directory? show a [mre] including a CMake presets file.

Comment: All configuration presets build to a seperate directory, i.e. build/win_x32, build/win_x64 etc. I will work on producing an example